# Cannot align text in Kivy Label

Tags: python, kivy

I want to populate a list from a file (here simplified) of list entries and then be able to scroll through the list. The individual list entries are structured like this:

```
-----------------------                   |
|nm_lbl               |                   |
-----------------------   |               |
|amt_lbl   |   sym_lbl|   } sub_sub_cont  } sub_cont
-----------------------   |               |
```

My approach is as follows:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

def populate_list(lst):
    lst.clear_widgets()
    inv_lst = [[123, "xyz", "abc"],[123, "xyz", "abc"],[123, "xyz", "abc"],
    [123, "xyz", "abc"]]

    for i in inv_lst:
        sym_lbl = Label(text=str(i[0]), size_hint_y=None, height=15, halign="right")
        nm_lbl = Label(text=str(i[1]), size_hint_y=None, height=15, halign="left")
        amt_lbl = Label(text=str(i[2]), size_hint_y=None, height=15, halign="left")

        sub_cont = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=2, size_hint_y=None)
        sub_cont.add_widget(nm_lbl)
        sub_sub_cont = GridLayout(cols=2, rows=1, size_hint_y=None)
        sub_cont.add_widget(sub_sub_cont)
        sub_sub_cont.add_widget(amt_lbl)
        sub_sub_cont.add_widget(sym_lbl)

        lst.add_widget(sub_cont)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return container

some_list=GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_y=0)
populate_list(some_list)

container = GridLayout(cols=1)
scroller = ScrollView()
container.add_widget(scroller)
scroller.add_widget(some_list)

app = MainApp()
app.run()
```

This code works as intended except for the fact that all of the text is centered in its respective Label, even though I'm using `halign="right"` or `halign="left"` on the Labels.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You need to set the label's text_size to it's size after it's been instantiated.

```
sym_lbl = Label(text=str(i[0]),
                size_hint_y=None,
                height=15,
                halign="right")
sym_lbl.text_size = sem_lbl.size
```

Also, the code you posted doesn't work for me and is poorly formatted. It looks like you made some errors posting your code in haste, maybe.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the code. I had some indentation problems. And thanks for your help, your solution worked perfectly!